# how to referesh list with help of lazy adapter into baseadapter in android

Tags: android, baseadapter, lazylist, android-lazyadapter

How to refresh list with help of  lazy adapter into base adapter in android...?

i am using navigation dwarwer from http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/ my image not downloaded properly in list and how to image clickable in  custom list view.?

```
   public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        // displaying count
        // check whether it set visible or not
        if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
            txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        }else{
            // hide the counter view
            txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Explain "my image not downloaded properly" please.

Comment: Are you adding the image from server dynamically to the list?

Comment: I have also problem with download image from server.? ?  every text and image on list.... i want  know how to click and redirect to another activity  please provide me some important link...and code on my email id thanks......suryaprakashchamoli@gmail.com

Comment: @Sufian means probleam in download image from server